# Embedding an inline video on facebook wall

Tags: facebook, video, jwplayer

Can someone please confirm that if is possible to share videos on facebook using jwplayer and they play with in facebook? Something like Vimeo, Youtube or DailyMotion.

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/property-types/#video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up OG tags to do this.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/blog/19150/publish-your-videos-to-facebook-with-a-jw-player